# NSDate hours are not correct after constructing date from components

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to construct a date from two different dates.  When I break down both dates into their respective components and re-assemble them into the new date.. everything seems to be correct except the hours.  Im sure its something simple that has to do with the timezone or the NSGregorianCalendar, but I am new to iOS, and programming NSCalendar.  Im hoping someone will catch the simple mistake Im making.

```
//grab today's date so we can brek it down into components
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Todays Date: %@", todayDate);

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//break down the stored date into components
NSDateComponents *theTime = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:storedIncorrectDate];

NSLog(@"Incorrect Calendar Components %@", theTime);

NSDateComponents *todayCalendarComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:todayDate];

NSInteger currentYear = [todayCalendarComponents year];

NSLog(@"The Year: %i", currentYear);

NSInteger currentMonth = [todayCalendarComponents month];

NSLog(@"The Month: %i", currentMonth);

NSInteger currentDay = [todayCalendarComponents day];

NSLog(@"The Day: %i", currentDay);


NSLog(@"Today's Calendar Components %@", todayCalendarComponents);


NSInteger theHours = [theTime hour];

NSLog(@"Hours: %i", theHours);

NSInteger theMinutes = [theTime minute];

NSLog(@"Minutes: %i", theMinutes);


NSInteger theSeconds = [theTime second];

NSLog(@"Seconds: %i", theSeconds);

//build my new date and store it before we play the affirmation.
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];


[components setHour:theHours];
[components setMinute:theMinutes]; 
[components setSecond:theSeconds]; 
[components setYear:currentYear];
[components setMonth:currentMonth];
[components setDay:currentDay];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];


NSLog(@"The Components: %@", components);

NSCalendar *updatedCal = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                          initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *revisedCorrectedDate = [updatedCal dateFromComponents:components]; 

NSLog(@"The Hours: %i", theHours);

NSLog(@"The New and Corrected Date: %@", revisedCorrectedDate);
```

The result of the log printing the revisedCorrectedDate shows everything correct that I set except the hours.  This has to be a simple fix.. I just don't see it.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's incorrect?  When I run this code, I get:

> 2012-06-03 18:13:36.130 Untitled[39805:707] The New and Corrected
>   Date: 2012-06-04 01:13:36 +0000

It's currently 6/3/12 18:13:36 here, and the date displayed is 6/4/12 01:13:36, which is the correct time, in UTC (notice the +0000 at the end).

Comment: zpastermack... your correct.  Investigating a few things now and will respond once I dig in a bit.  Thanks so much so far. Stay tuned!

Comment: zpastermack, if you have any quick ideas to save me a bit of research, this is what Im trying to do. I just need to convert UTC to the local timezone, store it in the DB in standard date formatting.

Comment: Figured it out.. was my first time altering NSDate by using components.  Realized that when it stores my UTC time in the DB, it converts it to my local time.